# Continuity of current through inductor

Tags: electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, inductance, electronics

I also know that sudden change of current is impossible as $V=L\frac{di}{dt}$, it makes infinite voltage.

But is there any other explanation about it?

Comment: what *other* type of explanation would you like to see, what is missing in this?

Comment: i think it is too much like proof of contradiction, i want any other type's explanation @hyportnex

Comment: Well, of course we build the theory around observations of things like the consequences of a sudden current change in an inductor. The behavior of inductors explains why the theory is what it is.  If you want proof, wind an inductor and see what it does. Mathematics never proves anything in physics.

Answer (score 0):

Sudden change of current $I$ is impossible,
because the [magnetic field energy in the inductor](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/indeng.html)
$$E=\frac 12 LI^2$$
cannot change suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

That the macroscopic current $i$ be a continuous function of time is an *assumption* in the lumped element modeling of an inductor. The macroscopic current is the result of the spatial and temporal statistical averaging of the motion of discrete particles (electrons/ions), just as the macroscopic fields are spatial and temporal averages of microscopic vacuum fields. The lumped element models of capacitors, inductors, resistors need that the macroscopic currents and/or voltages satisfy specific smoothness requirements within the realm of KVL and KCL; without those smoothness requirements the conservation of energy and charge could not be guaranteed, see the example of @ThomasFritsch below.

---

*Microscopic* current and potential are results of sums of discrete non-continuous and  non-finite impulses ("dirac deltas"). Macroscopic currents and voltages are averages both in time and in space of microscopic currents and potentials. To satisfy energy and charge conservation that are in the Maxwell equations of vacuum fields, when approximating macroscopically such fields using KCL/KVL, we *assume* that these currents through an inductor are continuous, and we *assume* that voltages across capacitors are continuous.

If our approximation is not quite right and our lumped model would imply non-continuous or non-conservative (energy/charge) behavior, then we modify the lumped element model of the circuit by not neglecting the resistance of the connecting wires, plates, and coil, or adding capacitive term(s) to the inductor or inductive term(s) to the capacitor. (There is capacitance and charge storage between windings of a coil, or currents flowing and induced magnetic fields on the plates, for example.) The model must always follow both energy and charge conservation that can only be assured if the currents through inductors and voltages across capacitors are assumed to be continuous and piece-wise differentiable (smooth); these are *assumptions* in the model circuit represented by the KCL/KVL equations.

Comment: Then, does any other elements(like resistor) have continuity of current and voltage?

Comment: All currents are motions of discrete charges. A macroscopic current of charges is a statistical average irrespective of it being a current through a resistor, an inductor or a capacitor. Since the electrons are point-like, the potential *at* the location of an electron is not meaningful, therefore, macroscopic voltage must also be an average. For consistency reasons, in the KVL and KCL, we *assume* that a current through an inductor and the voltage across the plates of a capacitor are continuous, while through a resistor no need for such requirement.

Comment: do you mean current and voltage actually discrete and not continuous, but to satisfy the conservation of energy and other requirement, it is assumed to be continuous? right?

Comment: see above the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

At the microscopic level, electric current is just the aggregate movement of charged particles. When the current is nonzero, it is not physically possible to discontinuously cut off the current because that would require discontinuously changing the velocities of all the charged particles to zero, i.e., the acceleration would need to be infinite, and there is no physical mechanism that can cause infinite acceleration. For any other discontinuous jump in the magnitude of current, it is also true that infinite acceleration would be required.